# Regularization in a 2D cylindrical spacetime

Tags: regularization, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I have a question about regularizing a stress tensor $T_{\mu \nu}$ for a scalar field in 2D cylindrical spacetime described in Birrell & Devies, `Quantum fields in curved space', pp. 90-92.

What I understand is that, in Minkowski spacetime, $T_{\mu \nu}$ can be regularized by taking a normal-ordering $\text{N}[T_{\mu \nu}]$. Also, one can show that $T^{\text{reg}}_{\mu \nu}:=T_{\mu \nu} - \langle 0_M|T_{\mu \nu} | 0_M \rangle$ is identical to $\text{N}[T_{\mu \nu}]$.
Here, $|0_M\rangle$ is the Minkowski vacuum.

$\star$What I don't understand is the rationale for $\langle 0_L|T^{\text{reg}}_{\mu \nu}| 0_L \rangle=\langle 0_L|T_{\mu \nu}| 0_L \rangle - \langle 0_M|T_{\mu \nu} | 0_M \rangle$ and say this is a way to regularize $T_{\mu \nu}$ in cylindrical spacetime.

I'm confused because there are other ways to do this in the same manner.
For example, I can start from the cylindrical spacetime and show that $T^{\text{reg}}_{\mu \nu}:=T_{\mu \nu} - \langle 0_L|T_{\mu \nu} | 0_L \rangle$ is identical to $\text{N}[T_{\mu \nu}]$, and state that the regularized vacuum expectation value in the cylindrical spacetime is $0$.
In this case, we are left with the regularization in the Minkowski spacetime, possibly obtaining a non-zero value.

...
I guess it is a matter of `benchmark' (if it makes sense) defining which vacuum state takes $T_{\mu \nu}$ to $0$ ?

Thanks in advance.